# After open the sales -> order listing page face this issue

Tags: discussion

**After open the sales -> order listing page face this issue in admin panel**

Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.
and find error alert, something went wrong with this message.

Sometime list open without error but sometime face this issue.

How to fix it some one help please ....

Comment: Have you checked your error log in var/log folder in Magento root ?

Comment: yes already check

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes when any field data not found in sales order table or sales order grid table. For fixed please follow these solutions.
Solution 1. Please check field value and insert the value in both tabls.
Solution 2. Please search sales_order_grid in ui_bookmark table and remove the same row in this table and then clear chache and check it again.